# How to access iOS simulator file system via SSH?

Tags: ios, xcode, ssh, terminal

Is it possible to establish an `SSH` communication from terminal to the iOS simulator? Can the file system on simulator be accessed via command line? Just for curiosity...

Comment: The simulator is an application that runs on your computer, so its files can be accessed via SSH in the same manner you would for anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS simulator files are in

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"big random number"/Data/Containers/

Run a NSLog with a file path from your project to find the big random number, or just prowl around until you find what you need.

You don't need to use ssh, the files are in your file system.